# How to make the content of one of the pages of the blogger takes full frame of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

This is a page https://ddc7hy.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_13.html
You will see that the video does not cover the entire page
I hope there is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code:

```css
      body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

#video-background {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

h1 span a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<video autoplay loop id="video-background" plays-inline>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
body, html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#blog {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It uses the viewport height and width to fill the whole viewport